# Are load in the car and fuel consumption linearly correlated?

Tags: forces

Just seeking tips on whether it's a good idea to be carry stuff that I may need on a daily basis.

Comment: This is an engineering question and is off-topic for this site.

Comment: The mass of the car probably makes the load mass negligible, unless you plan on hauling goats on a trailer every day.

Comment: There are too many confounding variables for us to answer this question with any degree of certainty. For such a complex system, the easiest thing to do would be to experiment for yourself. Perform your normal routine for a month (or however long is reasonable to you) with an unladen car and keep gas receipts or track fuel consumption for that time. Then switch and try carrying everything with you for the same length of time (again, doing your normal routine). Then compare the difference in fuel consumption. If it's more than 20% different, then go unladen

Comment: If you need it on a daily basis, of course you should carry it.

Comment: http://engineering.stackexchange.com - you are free to simply delete your question here and re-post it into there, it doesn't count spamming here.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main points two consider: The energy it costs to accelerate a car and the energy it costs to keep a car at a fixed velocity.

The energy you need to accelerate a car is proportional to the mass of the car. Therefore an increased load will increase the energy cost for accelerating the car. If you drive some form of hybrid car, some of this energy is recovered by charging the batteries while braking. The amount of recovered energy also scales linearly with the mass of the car. However, because of the energy losses at every energy conversion, a lighter car will always cost less energy to accelerate and decelerate.

The main contributions to energy dissipation in a car while keeping a constant velocity are [drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)) and [rolling resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance). Drag is independent of the mass of the car, while rolling resistance is approximately linearly related to the mass of the car. For low velocities, the rolling resistance will be the main cause of dissipation, while for high velocities, the drag is more important.

In the end it matters a lot, what type of car you have, what the weight is and what kind of trip you make. Therefore Jim's suggestion to test it in practice might be your best option.

Comment: The problem is not in energy dissipation, it's in energy acquisition. A heavier vehicle has more energy at driving speeds. Gaining this energy in similar time spans requires more power. More power translates directly to higher fuel consumption. There's definitely other factors that make a heavier vehicle use more fuel, but that's the bare-bones idealized physics that says it's unavoidable

Comment: @Jim. you are completely right of course. I updated my answer